# Protect RESTful calls to register users from mobile

Tags: android, ios, api, rest, security

Users sign up in my platform from the mobile app (Android & iOS). Once they have completed a form, I do a RESTful call to my server with the username and password and an API key.

```
https://api.example.com/v1/users/register
```

I assume that the API key is not protected since it is embedded in the app, so anyone can actually make that RESTful call and register as many users as they want.

How can I protect this call so that users can sign up ONLY from the mobile app? How do other apps (e.g. Facebook, Twitter,...) solve this problem?

Comment: Facebook and Twitter allow also to register from web client, no?

Comment: Check in your api from which device call is coming from. Act accordingly.

Comment: @Sanandrea yes, you can do web and app. My question is how do they protect it when it happens from the app.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 is there a way to know what device id or the app where the request comes from? I only know how to get the originating IP address.

Comment: @Arturo take a look at https://github.com/sanandrea/CSecretKey, it is NOT secure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I protect this call so that users can sign up ONLY from the
>   mobile app? How do other apps (e.g. Facebook, Twitter,...) solve this
>   problem?

There is no way to restrict your RESTful call just for mobile phones. Anybody could emulate that call impersonating a device manipulating headers or whatever. The only way to face this problem is to have a good security protocol design between your app and your backend.

As you mentioned, Facebook and other big companies do not store any API Key since the beginning in their app, instead they allow users to sign up through a website or mobile setting up specific user credentials. These signing ups are protected agains massive registration attacks using anti-bot techniques both from client (CAPTCHA) and server side (source IP + timings). Once those credentials are created and authenticated, their endpoint will return a client specific token which would be valid to make further REST API calls, and only this very user will be authorized to use that token for a limited period of time. One typical approach nowadays is to use [Oauth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) as you can see in many public API specifications like: [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/), [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview), [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens), etc. I suggest to research other famous REST API specifications, you can learn a lot from them.

Almost all of known techniques mentioned before like CAPTCHA, server side checks and so on could be defeated by a hacker. However, if you still want to add some additional barriers to avoid unlimited user accounts, one good idea can be to add two-step verification process to verify an account. Unless this process is finished correctly, the user won't be able to use your backend API (apart from the one to authorize the account). Thus, a user may be able to create a few accounts with different phone numbers, but never an unlimited amount of them.

Comment: This token security that Oauth 2 uses works well once the user already has an account. What about when the user doesn't and signs up from mobile? You can register on Facebook via their mobile app. Can anyone emulate that call from the command line and create a single Facebook account? Not talking about bots, but humans.

Comment: Yes you could. What you could not do is perform N registrations in a row due to they detect where those calls are coming from and detect them as irregular returning an error. But this is the last server side layer, as I said they have other client side protection layers like the popular CAPTCHA one.

Comment: @Arturo I've improved my original answer adding a new idea, hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to devise a flow like [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/). Its documentation may give you a hint.

Comment: I want to prevent it as well for humans that have not downloaded the app. The reason is that the app won't be publicly available, but on invitation base only (to my clients). I can't allow anyone to create an account.

Comment: Then you should base the registration on the account that you have provisioned.